# What is an example of an algebraic number of second order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I am looking for an example for an algebraic number of **second-order**.

I understand that we call any complex number is algebraic if it is a root for a polynomial.

**Ex:** $z^2+1=0$, then $z=i,-i$, so $i,-i$ are algebraic.

I want a brief explanation for an algebraic number of second order, and some examples.

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: I've never heard the term "second-order" in the way you are using it. Where did you come across it?

Comment: I am reading one research related to DE, and they use an algebraic number of second order.

Comment: Do you mean second degree? As in infinite periodic continued fractions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We say x is an algebraic number iff its a root of a monic polynomial with rational coefficients and the order of an algebraic number is the degree of its minimal polynomial.
[Look at the properties in Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number)

Comment: I have never seen the word *order* used for that: we say *degree*.